# Смена картинки при наведении курсора

Tags: jquery

Для картинки прописана смена изображения при наведении курсора

```
<a href="" class="b-socials__link"><img src="images/icon_social-heart_big.png" 
                onmouseover="this.src='images/icon_social-heart_small.png'"
                onmouseout="this.src='images/icon_social-heart_big.png'"
                alt=""></a>
```

подскажите, как переписать этот код на jQuery, чтобы картинка менялась не при наведении и отводе курсора, а чтобы изображения с периодичностью сменяли друг друга, когда мышка наведена на картинку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('img').hover(function() {
        var _this = this,
            images = _this.getAttribute('data').split(',');
            counter = 0;
        this.setAttribute('data-src', this.src);    
        //
        _this.timer = setInterval(function() {
            if(counter > images.length) {
                counter = 0;
            }
            _this.src=images[counter];

            counter++;
        }, 500);

    }, function() {
        this.src = this.getAttribute('data-src');    
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    });
});
</script>

<img src='http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png' data='http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png,http://careers.hashcode.ru/images/vacancies_banner_head.png,http://meta.hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo_4.png'>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, только в скрипте пришлось изменить if(counter > images.length) на if(counter > (images.length-1)), потому что иначе перещелкивало три изображения, а у меня только два))
а что нужно добавить в этот код, чтобы если отводишь мышку в тот момент, когда там "перещелкнутая" картинка, автоматом возвращалась первоначальная?

Comment: на счет однушки да, забыл)) По поводу вопроса: однозначно нужно где-то хранить первоначальное значение. Либо мы его будем запоминать, прежде чем подставлять другой src, либо хранить в атрибутах картинки. Я предпочел бы второй способ, он проще. Т.е. при наведении (в первой функции) добавляем изображению атрибут: 
this.setAttribute('data-src', this.src);// при отведении мыши обновляем src картинки на ссылку, что находится в data-src, т.е. : this.src = this.getAttribute('data-src'); Если не понимаете, как работает this, то почитайте: //javascript.ru/tutorial/object/thiskeyword очень полезно знат

Comment: про this я более-менее представляю)) а вы не могли бы написать код, который нужно внести в скрипт, чтобы это реализовать, а то вот это я не совсем понимаю, как прописать.

Comment: @Heidel, обновил пост.

Comment: а, понятно. большое спасибо))